# Rails errors[:base] inside class method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

Ok, after almost two hours of searching the web and not finding an answer to my question, I will ask it here.

I have this method in my

**class MatchesController < ApplicationController**

```ruby
def import
  if Match.find_by_match_id(params[:match_id])
    redirect_to matches_url, notice: "Match already imported."
  else
    Match.import(params[:match_id], params[:league_id])
    # error handling here?
    redirect_to matches_url, :flash => { :success => "Match imported successfully." }
  end
end
```

in my

**class Match < ActiveRecord::Base**

```ruby
def self.import(match,league)
    begin
      transaction do
        uri = URI('https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchDetails/V001/')
        params = { :match_id => match,
                   :key => "MY KEY" }

        uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
        http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
        http.use_ssl = true
        http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
        resp = http.request(request)

        data = resp.body

        result = JSON.parse(data)

        if result['result']['error']
          errors[:base] << "No Match with given ID found" 
          #self.errors.add_to_base("No Match with given ID found")
          break
        end

        match = result['result']
        players = match['players']
        pickban = match['picks_bans']
        leagueid = match['leagueid']

        if league != leagueid
          errors.add_to_base("This Match doesn't belong to the selected League")
          break
        end
      end
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid
      # not yet implemented
    end
end
```

Now when I import a match and it is not found I want to add an error that I can display to the user, but I get this error

```
undefined local variable or method `errors' for #<Class:0x007fde27cba478>
```

What am I doing wrong here? And how can I display the error via a `flash`to the user?

Comment: `errors` is an instance variable; if you're not calling this on an instance you'd need to use a different mechanism.

Comment: I know, but what would be a better mechanism? I was already searching the Web for quite a while for a solution.

Comment: Return something from `import` and expose it in flash or as a controller instance variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#errors` is an instance method, and you're calling it on the `Match` class. You could write the `import` method to have a return value of either 'Match imported successfully' or an error message.

Comment: So you mean instead of the break to get out of the `do` I should use `return` with the error message? And how do I catch this in my controller then? To use `if Match.import(params[:match_id], params[:league_id])` in my controller I can only return true or false in my class method, right?

Comment: `msg = Match.import(params[:match_id], params[:league_id])`, then you can choose where to redirect or what to render in the controller by looking at what `msg` is.